# Javascript timer delay

Tags: javascript, timer, html5-canvas, delay

I've decided to play around with HTML5's canvas, and of course that means I'm going to try writing a pong game. At the moment, I am trying to figure out how to cap my framerate. This is fairly easy in other languages, but finding a way to delay execution in Javascript seems to be a bit tougher.

Here is what I have so far:

```
while(true) {
    var begin = (new Date()).getTime();

    //Draw stuff to the canvas

    var end = (new Date()).getTime();
    if ((end-begin) < 33.333 ) {
        //delay (1000/(30-(end-begin)))
    }
}
```

Obviously, frame rates will be wildly different due to how each javascript engine performs, but I want to cap the maximum framerate at 30FPS. I don't really see how setTimeout() would accomplish this task. What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Have you tried `setInterval`? There are certainly some issues to be aware of, like a non-linear clock but at least this allows you to 'sleep' a bit.

Comment: Check out [requestAnimationFrame (click me)](http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/), it will give you about a 60ish FPS (or whatever best fits the client).

Comment: Related to the above comment: programmers.stackexchange.com/questions/175934/whats-the-best-way-to-use-requestanimationframe-and-fixed-frame-rates

Answer (score 7):

There is no `delay` / `wait` in JavaScript. You can use functions like [`window.setTimeout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/DOM/window.setTimeout) to call a function after certain time has elapsed, example:

```
window.setTimeout(function() {
    // do something interesting
}, 2000 /* but after 2000 ms */);
```

Or say you want to paint a frame every 33 ms (~30 fps), you will code it like:

```
window.setInterval(function() {
    // paint my frame 
}, 33);
```

Comment: I think it is `window.setInterval` rather than `window.setTimeInterval`.